# Is it wrong for one to skip Tachanun at Shacharis?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, tachanun

So i've asked this question before but with different manner.
I only really have the kavanah and focus for tachanun at mincha but not really at Shacharis and therefore have trouble deciding wether to omit it or not and just jump to ashrei-uva letzion before aleinu. Is it wrong for me to do that as a yachid davening at home ? Also not to mention its an optional tefillah as its done privately, sounds like its up to the one davening wether he wants that private time or not after the amidah. I have more feeling and kavanah for it at mincha but hardly at Shacharis.

Comment: מתוך שלא לשמה בא לשמה

Comment: Feels like you are asking the same question in a different way, looking for an answer that will satisfy you .... lucky for you you got a nice one below. My advice would be to speak with a Rav and tell him where you stand in your Jewish practice, and ask for advice what to do in your particular situation. This site cannot replace an honest conversation. I can say that, everytime I did this, I came back with good answers that helped me progress

Comment: The same goes for many other questions you've posted here (on this account and the previous). This is not the right forum for personal guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Tefillah can be a challenge. I would advise finding the best way that suites you, whilst also complying with at least a minimal standard of halacha. The tefillah we have nowadays in the siddur is a mixture of tefillot that are obligatory and not. However, many of the non-obligatory parts have become a strong part of the minhag of tefillah. That is not to say that one must say them all at any cost.

Furthermore, if you dont have kavanah for tachanum, the answer may not be "not saying it at all" but rather: figuring a way to make it meaningful for you. That could be, shortening it, reading a translation, saying it every other day, writing your own personalised abridged version, etc.

You could ask yourself what it is about the mincha tachanun that resonates with you, and how can you channel that into the shacharit tachanun.

Also, anecdotally, Rav Hershel Schachter has written that for the long tachanun on Monday and Thursday, he would only say half of it* because he finds that minyanim say it too quickly. We can learn from this that it *is* sometimes (always?) appropriate to go for quality over quantity. If there are a few sentences that are meaningful for you, focus on that.

I find that if you hold on to a little, it could be a seed thats planted for the future. If you have some roots to hold on to, it could flourish into a tree. In the same way, don't discard tachanun entirely, do something small and meaningful for you, and see where it goes.

*I think he would say one half on Monday and the other half on Thursday